# How to use ClickOnce with the new SDK style .csproj project format?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, csproj

When creating a "Windows Application" project in the new .NET SDK style project format for .NET 472, there is no "Publish" section in the project properties to configure the ClickOnce deployment.

[image: Project Properties]

Is there any solution/workaround to use ClickOnce with the new project format?

Comment: What is specifically "WinExe"? That project template doesn't exist. What .NET version does that project target?

Comment: That is "Windows Application" for net framework 472.

Comment: Ensure you have ClickOnce tools selected on Visual Studio Installer, because I publish .NET projects quite often

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Do you use the new .csproj project format with transitive nuget references? If i create a windows application with the old format, the publish tab is there and it works normally.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can publish a single file out of such projects (WinForms/WPF). ClickOnce or MSI is less useful here.

Comment: What I'm looking for is the ClickOnce feature that updates the application on the user side when starting the application.

Comment: For years, it still not support to publish clickonce application. I send a new request,  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/SDK-style-project-which-target-net48-abl/10185955